# What do this color difference stand for?

Tags: interface

[image]

I think that there must be reason for dividing tools by colors. What do each colors(green?, violet?) stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Green Tools are tools that add new geometry to your model, like poly build, spin, extrude, ...

Violet tools modify existing geometry, so most of the time they change vertex locations. Smooth is a good example of that category.

Comment: you are genius!